# How to select all column except few in beeline connection query

Tags: hadoop, hive, beeline

As we all know we can exclude column and selecting all other columns,
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;

select `(col_21)?+.+` from <table_name>

But, My questions how to use it beeline connection execution beeline -e

When I tried , I got an error like  Syntax error near unexpected token `?+.+`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a view on top of the table with just the columns you want? Then you can say "Select *" and mean it?

```
CREATE VIEW [IF NOT EXISTS] view_name [(column_list)]
AS select_statement;
```

Comment: I tried to use above option to select all column from table which has many columns except one to avoid naming all columns manually. To create view again I need to list the all columns. This won't help.

Comment: Well it is a write them all out once, and then re-use strategy. But once you have done this, your done.  It's a permanent fix instead or a per query fix.